# Mobile First Platform 8.0 Push notification failed on MacOS High Sierria

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I created created Push Notification App(it's cordova app) and MFPPush.registerDevice was succeeded. But "send notification" through MFPConsole(http://localhost:9080/mfpconsole/index.html#/mfp/push/echoview2.MFP8Sample#sendPush) failed.

I think MFP Server may use the IPv6 IP address as its own server IP address.

Anyone can find workaround?

Environment
+ OS: Mac OS High Sierria
+ MFP8: Product version: 8.0.0.00-20180315-134705

```
[err] com.ibm.mobile.analytics.sdk.events.AnalyticArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MSAN018E: The supplied value was invalid: fe80:0:0:0:9787:db29:a3d:b9e9%utun0 for serverIpAddress.
[err]   at com.ibm.mobile.analytics.sdk.model.PushNotification.setServerIpAddress(PushNotification.java:197)
[err]   at com.ibm.mobile.analytics.sdk.events.PushNotification.<init>(PushNotification.java:37)
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.analytics.plugin.AnalyticsPlugin.sendNotificationDispatchEvent(AnalyticsPlugin.java:172)
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.Mediator.fireNotificationDispatchEvent(Mediator.java:236)
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection.sendNotification(ApplicationConnection.java:146)
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.APNSMediator.sendNotification(APNSMediator.java:124)
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.Mediator$2.run(Mediator.java:105)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[err] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MSAN018E: The supplied value was invalid: fe80:0:0:0:9787:db29:a3d:b9e9%utun0 for serverIpAddress.
[err]   ... 12 more
[ERROR   ] Couldn't send message after 3 retries.Message(Id=2; Token=3BAE6CECD27D2DF48920AF230BE02A7FC3699480529AAAD17D1C27235B6C33C5; Payload={"payload":"{\"nid\":\"46403e8\",\"tag\":\"Push.ALL\"}","aps":{"alert":{"action-loc-key":null,"body":"Foo"}}})
Connection closed by remote host
[ERROR   ] FPWSE1083E: Failure sending Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) notification with identifier 2, device token: 3BAE6CECD27D2DF48920AF230BE02A7FC3699480529AAAD17D1C27235B6C33C5.
Connection closed by remote host
[err] Exception in thread "pool-9-thread-3" 
[err] com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
[err]   at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.wrapAndThrowAsRuntimeException(Utilities.java:277)
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:319)
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
[err]   at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[err] Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
[err]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1565)
[err]   at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:124)
[err]   at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
[err]   ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a configuration error. MFP Push needs to communicate with apple notifications servers (called APNS) in order to successfully send notifications.
It looks like mobilefirst in your case is unable to communicate with the APNS servers. You need to explicitly configure this. Instructions on configuring push notifications proxy for both APNS and GCM (Google cloud messaging for android) can be found [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/10/configure-push-notification-proxy/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I resolved this problem. I mistook the certificate type for push notification. I changed it from production to sandbox, then sending push work fine(I need not to configure proxy).

Comment: The message 'MSAN018E: The supplied value was invalid: fe80:0:0:0:9787:db29:a3d:b9e9%utun0 for serverIpAddress.
' is shown yet, but push notification succeed.  It seems that if I add the '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to  mfp-server/usr/servers/mfp/jvm.options, this message will dismiss.